# How to implement dompdf in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

I just making website that can make html file into pdf using cakephp 3 as php framework.

this is my code in layout as default.ctp for pdf view that i want to convert

```
<?php  
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php'); 
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload'); 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->set_paper = 'A4';
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($content_for_layout), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->output();
```

when i try to run it, it some error like this

```
Error: Class 'Configure' not found 
File C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\src\Template\Layout\pdf\default.ctp 
Line: 6
```

is my syntax for calling dompdf is not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not dompdf error.
It is because of this `Configure::read('App.encoding')`.

Write this on top of your file  and your code should work.
`use Cake\Core\Configure;`